# Creating grid with invisible border

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a windows phone app. I need to create a 3X3 grid like structure. I want the border to be invisible initially. When a user touches a border, it should become visible. Kindly give me some guidance how to get started . I am new to windows phone framework. Also, can it be done in silverlight or I need xna ?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is good. Add a grid with 3 columns and 3rows and columns

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

then add border elements to every row*column, something like this:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var borders = new Border[3,3];
        var handler = new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(MainPage_Tap);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                borders[i,j] = new Border()
                                {
                                    BorderThickness = new Thickness(4),
                                    Opacity = 0,
                                    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
                                };
                borders[i, j].Tap += handler;

                Grid.SetRow(borders[i,j], i);
                Grid.SetColumn(borders[i,j], j);
                grid.Children.Add(borders[i, j]);
            }
    }

    void MainPage_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var snd = sender as Border;
        snd.Opacity = 1;
    }
```

I used an array of border so you can easily manipulate them later, but that's not really required.

EDIT: If you'd like border just around the whole grid, do the same thing with the tap event, but set the border in XAML like this

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Opacity="0" Tap="handler" />
</Grid>
```